# Apache maintenance page htaccess without being overriden by subfolder

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to perform a maintenance on my website, so wrote an htaccess (I do not own the server) to redirect users to a specific page.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !outoforder.html
RewriteRule .* "/outoforder.html" [R=503,L]
ErrorDocument 503 /outoforder.html
Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store"
</IfModule>
```

It is working well. However, in some subfolders I have also some rewriting rules that seem to override this rule, therefore I am still able to access those subfolders.
There are plenty of subfolders, so I do not want to modify all of them, to temporary disable the rewriting process, I would like to be able to do that in the root folder.

First I do not understand why those rules are still applied, I would have thought that due to `RewriteRule .* "outoforder.html" [R=503,L]` their files are not accessed then their writing rules should not be applied. Obviously, I am wrong.

Thus, how can I avoid the sub htaccess or disable from the root directory the ability to rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_rewrite is not inherited by default. So any mod_rewrite directives in a subdirectory/child `.htaccess` file will completely override the parent directives. Your mod_rewrite rule in the parent config that triggers the 503 is not even processed.

You can either enable mod_rewrite inheritance so that the directives from the current scope are processed *before* mod_rewrite directives in child configs. For example, in the parent config:

```
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
```

However, this could have many additional caveats. (`InheritDownBefore` also requires Apache 2.4.8+)

OR, use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive to trigger the 503 instead and use a negative lookahead in the regex to prevent the error document itself from triggering the maintenance page.

For example:

```
RedirectMatch 503 ^/(?!outoforder\.html).*
```

---

*Aside:* If using mod_rewrite...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !outoforder.html
> RewriteRule .* "/outoforder.html" [R=503,L]
> ```

This should be implemented in a single directive, for example:

```
RewriteRule !outoforder\.html$ - [R=503]
```

The *condition* was superfluous - this check can be performed (more efficiently) in the `RewriteRule` directive itself. When using a return status outside of the 3xx range then the *substitution* string is ignored anyway, so it is preferable to use a single hyphen instead (ie. `-`) to explicitly indicate no-substitution. The `L` flag is also redundant in this case for the same reason - it is implied.

A slight caveat with the solution(s) above is that a request for the `/outoforder.html` URL/file itself will result in a 200 OK response by default, unless you are overriding this in the file itself (although this may not be possible if it is plain HTML and not using any server-side scripting, eg. PHP).

You can resolve this by using the following rule instead:

```
# Trigger a 503 for ALL user requests
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=503]
```

This triggers a 503 for every *direct* request from the user, including requests for the 503 error document itself. The *condition* prevents the internal subrequest for the error document triggering another 503 response (infinite loop).

Comment: ```RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore``` did the job. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. However, enabling mod_rewrite inheritance can have additional caveats if you have other directives. Using mod_alias instead would be my preference.

Comment: ```RedirectMatch 503 ^/(?!outoforder\.html).*``` is also perfectly working. I take your advice !

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the `[L]` flag, you need to use the `[END]` flag.   From the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end)

> Using the `[END]` flag terminates not only the current round of rewrite processing (like `[L]`) but also prevents any subsequent rewrite processing from occurring in per-directory (`.htaccess`) context.

The other issue that I see with your rules is that the destination path (`"/outoforder.html"`) is never used on a `RewriteRule` with `[R=503]`.  I would recommend using `-` for clarity there.

So your final rule set should be:

```sh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !outoforder.html
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,END]
ErrorDocument 503 /outoforder.html
Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The explanation of the ```END``` looked very promising, however it is still not working. I can access to all the subfolders...

Comment: Looks like mrwhite has a better answer for you.  I'm glad his answer works.